# Markov chain problem

Tags: self-study

This problem comes out of Intro to probability models by Ross
The answer is given, but can't understand how it was arrived

Question. A particle moved on a circle through 0,1,2,3,4 in clockwise 
orders at each step it has probability of p of moving to the right or 1-p
to the left.
Let X_n denote its location on the circle after the nth step.   find the transition matrix

Help

Comment: Create a 5x5 matrix with empty cells.  Label the rows with the numbers 0,1,...,4, corresponding to the state you are in at any stage.  Label the columns with the numbers 0, 1,...,4 corresponding to the state you will be in at the next stage.  Now, fill in each cell with the appropriate probability; cell (2,3) (row 2, column 3) for example, would be the probability of transitioning from state 1 to state 2.  Does this match the final answer?

Comment: I don't know. Here is row 1  (0,p, 0,0,1-p) Go to left (0,p, 0,0,0) go to right (1-p, p, 0,0 ,0)

Comment: What is "go to left" "go to right"?  There should be a 5x5 matrix, that's all.

Comment: "Move to the right" probably means "Move to the next higher state, unless at state 4, in which case you move to state 0", and "Move to the left" probably means "move to the next lower state, unless at state 0, in which case you move to state 4".  Draw the circle with the five stages on it, so you have a diagram, and don't get confused by how "move to the right" changes when you reach the bottom of the circle.  Does Ross provide a diagram?  Is that question word-for-word quoted above?

Comment: Yes he does in chapter 2 and I tried it and it doesn't help it much. I am noobie with Markov chain

Comment: This is a very simple exercise . Can you please have a go?

Comment: Welcome to the site! I would try $\begin{bmatrix}\color{blue}{\text{transition }\Pr\text{ distribution:}}\\\color{red}{\text{states:}}&\color{blue}0&\color{blue}1&\color{blue}2&\color{blue}3&\color{blue}4\\\color{red}0&0&p&0&0&1-p\\\color{red}1&1-p&0&p&0&0\\\color{red}2&0&1-p&0&p&0\\\color{red}3&0&0&1-p&0&p\\\color{red}4&p&0&0&1-p&0 \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: You may find this [post on Toeplitz matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) interesting.

Answer (score 3):

When I was new to Discrete Time Markov Chains (DTMCs), I always started by drawing the *Transition Diagram* before the *Transition Probability Matrix*.

I still find it helpful. Perhaps this will help.

[image: Transition Diagram]

Edit:  For completeness, the *Transition Probability Matrix* is straightforward from the picture. Let the state space be ${0, 1, 2, 3, 4}$.

$$P = 
\begin{bmatrix}
   0 & p & 0 & 0 & 1-p \\
   1-p & 0 & p & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1-p & 0 & p & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1-p & 0 & p \\
   p & 0 & 0 & 1-p & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$